# Make image size animate when container height/width is changed using css3?

Tags: html, css, translation

I want my image size to animate smoothly using a css3 transition when the parent container size changes.

The css works fine if I set height/width properties to my images -- for example

```
transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
```

(simplified) markup

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="myimage.png" style="width: 200px;"></li>

    <li><img src="myimage.png" style="width: 200px;"></li>

    <li><img src="myimage.png" style="width: 200px;"></li>
</ul>
```

but this does not seem to work -- they just jump to the next size.

```
<ul style="width: 200px;">
    <li><img src="myimage.png"></li>

    <li><img src="myimage.png"></li>

    <li><img src="myimage.png"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the width of each image to 100%.

And this is the code that I used for image animations:

```
transition-property: width;
transition-duration: 1s;
-webkit-transition-property: width; /* Safari */
-webkit-transition-duration: 1s; /* Safari */
```